# Datepicker for Bootstrap (bootstrap-datepicker.js) Google Chrome prev and next arrows

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, bootstrap-datepicker

jQuery 1.9.1

bootstrap 2.3.2

Google Chrome (Version 31.0.1650.63 m)

[image]

All other browsers

[image]

The prev and next values are set in the bootstrap-datepicker.js as `&lsaquo;` and `&rsaquo;`

Any ideas as to why only Chrome shows these characters incorrectly?

As suggested, here is a link to a JSFiddle. Surprisingly I cannot replicate the issue here. It works fine.
http://jsfiddle.net/QaujD/

But going directly to the site to download Datepicker for Bootstrap bootstrap-datepicker.js, the issue can be seen in the latest version of Chrome. http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-datepicker/

Comment: Reckon you could edit in a JSFiddle or comment with some other demo link that exhibits the problem when you view it in Chrome? It would be helpful if we could rapidly check whether we get the same behaviour when viewing that example, or whether it's an issue specific to your particular Chrome install.

Comment: @mark-amery Thanks for the suggestion. I have updated with links.

Comment: I'm on Chrome 31.0.1650.63 as well and everything looks fine for me on  http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-datepicker/. First, clear your cache and see if the issue persists. If it does, my best guess is that you have a corrupted font installed on your system, though I dunno why you'd see different behaviour on JSFiddle if that were the cause. On both JSFiddle and eyecon.ro, right click the arrow, hit inspect element, choose the 'computed' tab and scroll down till you see what font is being used. For me, it's Liberation Sans on both sites.

Comment: @mark-amery I spoke with another dev after getting them to try the 2 links. They also see the issue at http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-datepicker/ but not on the fiddle site. They mentioned an existing issue with Chrome where certain fonts aren't rendering correctly and that there is an Alpha/Beta that addresses this issue. I looked at the css and saw that the font-family inherited from body lists "Helvetica Neue" first. Taking this out of the style displays the arrows.

Answer (score -1):

(Best Guess, also experienced this) Its your server! Some linux platform Apache servers cannot use the sprite images those two arrows are pulled from. try using fontawesome instead. http://fontawesome.io/

Comment: Given that he says he gets the same bug when viewing on [the library's demo page](http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-datepicker/), and that it only happens in a particular version of a particular browser, it's unlikely to be a problem with his server.